# Android Currency.getAvailableCurrencies() before API 19

Tags: android, currency

The method `getAvailableCurrencies` has been made available only since API 19 (Kitkat). Any ideas of how can I achieve the same result of `Currency.getAvailableCurrencies` in previous APIs?

(I am working on API 15)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will work both on API >= 19 and on API < 19.

It generates two CharSequence Arrays: one contains the currency codes in alphabetical order, the description of the corresponding currency currency (code + symbol + name of the currency).

```
List < String > entries = new ArrayList < String > ();
List < String > countries = new ArrayList < String > ();

int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

// API >= 19
if (currentapiVersion >= 19) {
    Set < Currency > currencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
    for (Currency currency: currencies) {
        try {
            String listItem = currency.getCurrencyCode() + " (" + currency.getSymbol() + ")" + " " + currency.getDisplayName();
            entries.add(listItem);
            countries.add(currency.getCurrencyCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

// API < 19
else {
    ArrayList < String > currencies = new ArrayList < String > ();
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (Locale locale: locales) {
        try {
            String val = Currency.getInstance(locale).getCurrencyCode();
            if (!currencies.contains(val))
                currencies.add(val);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // Locale not found
        }
        Collections.sort(currencies);
    }
    for (String currencyCode: currencies) {
        try {
            Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
            String listItem = currency.getCurrencyCode() + " (" + currency.getSymbol() + ")" + " " + currency.getDisplayName();
            entries.add(listItem);
            countries.add(currency.getCurrencyCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

// Result
CharSequence[] resultEntries = entries.toArray(new CharSequence[entries.size()]);
CharSequence[] resultCountries = countries.toArray(new CharSequence[countries.size()]);
```

Comment: `Currency.getDisplayName()` is API 19 too.

Comment: If anyone knows of an equivalent, pre-API 19 solution for `Currency.getDisplayName()` please post your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349116/how-to-get-a-currencys-display-name-before-android-api-19

Comment: should `CharSequence[] stati = daConvertire.toArray` be `CharSequence[] stati = statiDaConvertire.toArray` instead?