# How to get a currency's display name before Android API 19?

Tags: java, android, locale, currency

[`Currency.getDisplayName(java.util.Locale)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html#getDisplayName(java.util.Locale)) is exactly what I want... except it's only available since Android API 19. That's no good as my `minSdkVersion` < 19.

Does anyone know how to get the locale-specific display name for a currency before API 19? Preferably without having to use a third-party library.

This question can alternatively be expressed as:

How can you get the equivalent of [`Currency.getDisplayName(java.util.Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getDisplayName(java.util.Locale)) before Java 7?

Comment: Note I have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458912/can-i-get-a-text-description-of-an-iso-currency-code-in-java but I'm hoping a better solution's emerged since then  - i.e., not using a third-party library or digging into the Java source code.